# How to list "only" startup applications through the terminal on Fedora 24

Tags: mate-desktop, autostart

How to list in the terminal "only" start-up applications (the ones that you find normally in "Startup Application Preferences" Dialog box on Fedora Mate Desktop). This question can be generalized to Ubuntu or any other Linux Distro.

Answer (score 1):

Typically user configured autostart applications are in `~/.config/autostart`.

You can make a `.desktop` file to add new autostart applications. See the end of this answer for an example .desktop file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think the file exist on Fedora 24. Any alternatives?

Comment: It's not a file, it's a folder that you can add files to. See the end of this answer for an example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: That is not my question. I don't want to add anything to start-up applications (by putting a .desktop file). I just want to list them through shell (terminal). in other words I want to list the exact list in the GUI form of start-up applications. Maybe redirect the content to a text file later

Comment: If you run "ls -alh ~/.config/autostart" you should see a list of applications that are autostarted.

Comment: Sorry again. Thousand thank you for your help. It appears that I don't have a directory called autostart in the first place. "No such file or directory"

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/Exec/ {print "Command :",$0}'  ~/.config/autostart/*.desktop
```